# Crazy low fps when playback animation

Tags: performance

When I playback an animation I get around 1 FPS with really basic object.

My scene contains 1 Torus with standard vertex and array modifier set to 8. No Subdivision modifier and no texture or light, its really basic.

If I increase the array to maybe 70 count I'm not able to stop the animation and Blender most likely crashes.

I have tried different type of settings and updated my graphics driver, without improvement.

CPU Win 10 Home Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6400 CPU 2.70GHz 2.71 GHz 8g RAM 64-bit Bought last summer.

I have Blender and a couple of games on the computer I never use for anything else other then Blender normaly

When I play games I never have problems and normally play with high settings.

Comment: Any chance you could upload the .blend file? If someone else can test the file we can verify if it is a problem with the file or not. You can upload files here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the render tab under dimensions there is an option of frame rate, under which you may choose 60fps and give it a try. If it doesn't work than you can choose custom and go as high as possible. If even that doesn't work then you might try baking the animation first with very small timeframe and then play the animation.  HOPE IT HELPS.

Comment: These are animation rendering settings, not viewport performance adjustment.

Comment: Thanks fo the help! I did change it to 120 and now i have like 50 fps when i do first animition playbeck and after that the animation runs perfectly smoth. Thanks! Why does it run smother with higher FPS input in Demensions?